# Support exiting links to new site using angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I migrate a site to use angular and the ui-router. The URLs will now have `.../#!/...` in the address. Any existing links on social media etc pointing to elements with IDs i.e. `www.my-website.com/#help` will no longer work. Angular will redirect the URL to the root address.

Its a single page site so retaining the element addressing is important.

Does anyone know how to support the old urls in the new site?

Comment: Use html5 mode. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: JB Nizet you were first with the answer but I can't mark a comment as the answer - thanks for the quick response though - worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5mode. This lets Angular change the routing and URLs of pages without refreshing the page (and without the '#'). Here's how, briefly:

- In your app config function use:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to turn on HTML5 mode.

- Add base tag to your HTML head:

  ```
  <base href="/" />
  ```
- You server needs to be configured: See [How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).